# How to remove multiple elements in a NSMutableSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

We can remove multiple elements from `NSMutableArray` by using `removeObjectsInArray:` function. Does `NSMutableSet` have any similar function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `minusSet:` method to remove multiple elements from your mutable set, like this:

```
NSMutableSet *mySet = ...
[mySet minusSet:[NSSet setWithArray:myArray]];
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do they have different names for such similar functions?

Comment: @FlySoFast I think they made a different API on `NSMutableSet` because it takes an `NSSet` as a parameter, and also to be in line with naming of other set operations (i.e. intersect and union).